Durrett (5th Edition) Theorem 5.7.3 (Tail field of Markov Chain of period $d>1$)
The theorem states that

Given $X_0,X_1,\dots$ be an irreducible Markov chain with all states recurrent and of period $d>1$. Let $S_0,\dots,S_{d-1}$ be its cyclic decomposition. Then if $A$ is a tail event, then $A=\{X_0\in S_r\}$ for some $r\in \{0,\dots,d-1\}$ $P_\mu$ a.s.. Here $\mu$ is the initial distribution.

Maybe I seriously misunderstood something. Shouldn't a tail event be an event whose occurrence is unaffected by finitely number of random variables? But the above theorem says that the occurrence of tail event $A$ is determined by $X_0$.

Update: my question is more about a possible incompatbility between this theorem and an earlier statement saying that "intuitively, $A$ is a tail event if and only if changing a finite number of values doesn't affect the occurrence of the event" (P70, above Kolmogorov's 0-1 law.)
If I understand theorem 5.7.3 correctly, then $\{X_0\in S_r\}$ is a tail event. But changing a finite number of values does affect the occurrence of the event.
My current thought is that maybe I should be cautious with the only if part of the intuition on page 70 in presence of null sets. For example, consider process that $X_0=X_1=X_2=\dots$ and assume that $\mathcal{F}_n'$ is the completition of $\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$. Then the event that $\{X_0=x\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_n'$ as it differs from $\{X_n=x\}$ by a null set. If the occurrence of this event $\{X_0=x\}$ in $\mathcal{F}_n'$ is affected by changing the value of $X_0$, it seems that we cannot expect the occurrence of a tail event must be unaffected by changing a finite number of values.

I don't have the book. The MC is written ${X_n}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Perhaps it starts from $X_1$ and the author gives some other meaning to $X_0$.

@geetha290krm. My bad, I have editted the question to avoid confusion. The chain does start with $X_0$.

No, the theorem states that the tail $\sigma$-field is generated (modulo null sets) by the events $\{X_0\in S_r\}$.
The idea is that because of irreducible recurrence, if $X_0=i\in S_r$ then $X_{nd}\in S_r$ a.s. for all $n=1,2,\ldots$. The aperiodic "sub-chain" $Y_n:=X_{nd}$ has trivial tail $\sigma$-field. So any non-trivality in a tail event has to do with which of the parts $S_0,\ldots, S_{d-1}$ of the cyclic decomposition the chain started in.

Could you clarify the reason that the tail $\sigma$-field is generated by ${X_0\in S_r}$ makes a difference? The event ${X_0\in S_r}$ is still a tail event, right? And its occurrence is determined by the value of $X_0$?

Yes, the occurrence of the event $A:={X_0\in S_r}$ is determined by whether $X_0(\omega)\in S_r$. Notice that $A$ is a.s. equal to $B:={X_{99d}\in S_r}$ and also a.s equal to $C:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}{X_{nd}\in S_r}$. That is, $P(A\Delta B) =P(A\Delta C) =0$.
